# Implementing a custom counting system in Python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

In finance, futures contracts are usually represented by their expiry year and month. So for example, `201212` would be 2012 - December.

Some contracts, for example Corn, are only traded some months `[3,5,7,9,12]`, whereas sometimes, *you* might only want to trade the `[12]` contract (despite it trading other months too, so you'd trade `201212`, `201312` etc).

I'm currently using the the `int` format to represent these contracts in my system, and using that as a Pandas index.

The tricky thing is, given a contract, I often need to get the next contract (and to a lesser extent, the previous one).

I've written a generator expression that does something like this:

```
def contract_generator(self, recent=True, year=None, month=None, traded_only=False):
    if year is None:
        year = datetime.datetime.now().year - 1 if recent == True else self.first_contract

    if traded_only is True:
        months = self.trade_only
    else:
        months = self.months_traded

    months = deque(months)

    if month is not None:
        months.rotate(months.index(month)-1)
    while True:
        for month in months:
            yield {
                'year': year,
                'month': month,
                'contract': str(year)+str("%02d" % (month,)),
                'formatted_contract': self.contract_format(year, month),
                'expiration_date': self.expiration_date(year, month)
                }
        year+=1

def next_contract(self, contract):
    c = contract_to_tuple(contract)
    j = self.contract_generator(year = c[0], month = c[1], traded_only=False)
    return next(j)['contract']

def contract_to_tuple(contract):
    contract = str(contract)
    return (int(contract[0:4]),int(contract[4:6]))
```

(where `months_traded` & `trade_only` are the lists to which I referred to in paragraph 2).

Crucially, its buggy and the above doesn't work quite right. I can fix it, but to be honest, I really dislike this approach. There must be a better way.

Ideas:

- Implement using datetime somehow
- Create some kind of custom object, implement arithmetic operators so I can do `201212 + 1` to get the next contract (but would this really be easy with pandas?)
- I don't think python has it baked in, but perhaps I can define a custom numerical base somehow that maps to this behaviour.

Is there an easy/elegant way to do this that already exists? Or do I really need to make it from scratch?

**Edit**:

My final result:

```
def nc(self, contract, months=None):
    d = pd.to_datetime(str(contract), format='%Y%m')
    months_traded = deque(self.months_traded)
    months_traded.rotate(-1)
    output_month = months_traded[self.months_traded.index(d.month)]
    output_year = d.year + 1 * d.month==12
    return str(output_year)+str("%02d" % (output_month,))
```

Comment: Consider fixing the code anyway, then posting it on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead. That site's entire purpose is to make working code better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
def next_contract(contract, last=False):
    d = pd.to_datetime(str(contract), format='%Y%m')
    d += pd.offsets.MonthBegin(12 * (last * -2 + 1))
    return int(d.strftime('%Y%m'))
```

#### Demo

```
next_contract(201212)

201312

next_contract(201212, last=True)

201112
```

#### Explanation

```
def next_contract(contract, last=False):
    # convert contract to datetime with assumed format of yyyymm
    d = pd.to_datetime(str(contract), format='%Y%m')
    # use pandas offsets.  I don't care that it's month begin
    # because I'm ditching the day anyway.
    # (last * -2 + 1) equals -1 when last is True and 1 when last is False
    d += pd.offsets.MonthBegin(12 * (last * -2 + 1))
    return int(d.strftime('%Y%m'))
```

For what it's worth, here is a stub of a class.  Honestly, coding up all the handling for the other months should be left as an exercise for you.

```
class Corn(object):
    def __init__(self, contract):
        self.contract = contract

    def __add__(self, i):
        d = pd.to_datetime(str(self.contract), format='%Y%m')
        d += pd.offsets.MonthBegin(12 * i)
        self.contract = int(d.strftime('%Y%m'))
        return self

    def __sub__(self, i):
        return self.__add__(-i)

    def get_next(self):
        return self + 1

    def get_last(self):
        return self - 1

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.contract)
```

---

```
corn = Corn(201212)
print(corn + 1)
print(corn.get_next())

201312
201412
```

Comment: This is a much better approach than what I've got, but how do I cope with the limitations in paragraph 2 above (that is, sometimes the months to iterate through might be [3, 5, 7, 9, 12] or whatever)

Comment: I'll let you figure that part out.  You should have a better idea how to proceed now.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it set me in the right direction! I pasted my final solution above.